# модуль requests поддерживает прокси IPv6?

Tags: python, requests, ipv6

Всем привет! Вопрос: requests поддерживает IPv6? в документах указана только поддержка http и https как я понимаю IPv4. Если да, в каком формате их указывать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> requests поддерживает IPv6?

***requests*** по умолчанию использует *IPv6*, если хост поддерживает его. Кроме того в ***requests*** используется ***urllib3***, а точнее на данный момент `'urllib3>=1.21.1,<1.23'`. И все, что касается прокси в ***requests*** основано на `PoolManager, proxy_from_url` из `urllib3.poolmanager`. Таким образом, если возникают какие-то проблемы с *IPv6* прокси, надо смотреть решение проблем для ***urllib3***. 
Проблемы, связанные с *IPv6* в ***requests***, освещены [здесь](https://github.com/requests/requests/search?q=ipv6&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

> Если да, в каком формате их указывать?

```
proxies={"https":"http:[<ipv6:address>]:<portnumber>"}
```

`<ipv6:address>` - должен соответствовать [**rfc2732**](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt)